# Checking empty object

Tags: php, error-handling

Is there a better method for covering errors in my case? I am looking for best practice for now and future instances.

Foreseen errors that could arise:

- No attributes at all
- Some attributes could be missing
- Attribute value could be empty

---

```
// converting dom into array to use later
$fields = $dom->getElementsByTagName($field);
$arr['field'] = array();

foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $attributes = isset($field->attributes) ? $field->attributes : NULL;

    if (!empty($attributes)) {
        // the method getNamedItem($string) returns NULL if not found
        $name = !empty($attributes->getNamedItem('name')) ? $attributes->getNamedItem('name')->nodeValue : NULL;
        $id = !empty($attributes->getNamedItem('id')) ? $attributes->getNamedItem('id')->nodeValue : NULL;
        $field_name = !empty($attributes->getNamedItem('field_name')) ? $attributes->getNamedItem('field_name')->nodeValue : NULL;

        if (!empty($name) && !empty($id) && !empty($field_name)) {
            $arr['field'][$name][$id][$field_name] = $field->nodeValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is cleaner to handle special cases early; your code winds up less indented.

```
// converting dom into array to use later
$fields = $dom->getElementsByTagName($field);
$arr['field'] = array();

foreach ($fields as $field) {
  $attributes = isset($field->attributes) ? $field->attributes : NULL;

  if (empty($attributes)) {
    continue;
  }

  $name = !empty($attributes->getNamedItem('name')) ? $attributes->getNamedItem('name')->nodeValue : NULL;
  $id = !empty($attributes->getNamedItem('id')) ? $attributes->getNamedItem('id')->nodeValue : NULL;
  $field_name = !empty($attributes->getNamedItem('field_name')) ? $attributes->getNamedItem('field_name')->nodeValue : NULL;

  if (empty($name) || empty($id) || empty($field_name)) {
    continue;
  }

  $arr['field'][$name][$id][$field_name] = $field->nodeValue;
}
```

This looks less complicated, at least to me, but it does exactly the same work.

You could also introduce a method to get the nodeValue or NULL, given $attributes and a name.

```
// converting dom into array to use later
$fields = $dom->getElementsByTagName($field);
$arr['field'] = array();

foreach ($fields as $field) {
  $attributes = isset($field->attributes) ? $field->attributes : NULL;

  if (empty($attributes)) {
    continue;
  }

  $name       = nodeIfPresent($attributes, 'name');
  $id         = nodeIfPresent($attributes, 'id');
  $field_name = nodeIfPresent($attributes, 'field_name');

  if (empty($name) || empty($id) || empty($field_name)) {
    continue;
  }

  $arr['field'][$name][$id][$field_name] = $field->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: The second method looks very clean to me. Then I could reuse `nodeIfPresent` without having to have so many long `if else` shorthand statements.

Answer (score 2):

You can most definitely improve some on this code. First off: `DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName` returns an instance of the `DOMNodeList` class, which in turn consists of `DOMNode` instances. Checking what methods and properties these classes have to offer is a good place to start.
Anyway, I'll go through your code and suggest changes, and then explain why I suggest to change your approach:

```
$fields = $dom->getElementsByTagName($field);
$arr['field'] = array();
```

Yes, I have some remarks here already:
Are you 100% sure that the value of `$field` is always going to be a lower-case string (as is recommended to pass to `getElementsByTagName`? If not:

```
$fields = $dom->getElementsByTagName(
    strtolower(
        trim($field)//trim, lower-case
    )
);
```

Next: `$arr` isn't declared as an array anywhere. This issues a notice, so perhaps consider writing:

```
$arr = array(
    'field' => array()
);
```

Or just use `$arr = array();`, because as far as I can tell, the `$arr` array will only have one single key *"field"*, where all the data is stored. Why bother with that `field` key, then?

```
foreach ($fields as $field) {
```

Hold on a tick: `as $field`? But the variable `$field` was used as the value for the tag name. I'd consider using a different var name, perhaps something more descriptive for its contents: `$node` seems like a good fit.

```
    $attributes = isset($field->attributes) ? $field->attributes : NULL;

    if (!empty($attributes)) {
```

Why use a messy ternary followed by `!empty($attribtues)` when you are using an API that offers a clean from the bat:

```
if ($node->hasAttributes())
{
    //code here
}
```

I'd use the method, it's easy to read, and makes your code a lot easier to follow/maintain/debug.

```
        $name = !empty($attributes->getNamedItem('name')) ? $attributes->getNamedItem('name')->nodeValue : NULL;
        $id = !empty($attributes->getNamedItem('id')) ? $attributes->getNamedItem('id')->nodeValue : NULL;
        $field_name = !empty($attributes->getNamedItem('field_name')) ? $attributes->getNamedItem('field_name')->nodeValue : NULL;
```

Again: don't go ternary-crazy. `$node->attributes` is an instance of the `DOMNamedNodeMap` class, which indeed has a `getNamedItem` method. [Check the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnamednodemap.getnameditem.php). This method returns *either* a `DOMNode` instance or `null`, if the named item does not exist. Why use `!empty`? Wouldn't this be shorter:

```
$name = $node->attributes->getNamedItem('name');
```

The result is the same either way: `$name` will be an object, or `null`. The ternary just adds code-smell/noise/clutter.

```
        if (!empty($name) && !empty($id) && !empty($field_name)) {
            $arr['field'][$name][$id][$field_name] = $field->nodeValue;
        }
```

Again: I'd recommend you ditch the `field` key, and properly declare any array you plan on using. This code *will* emit notices (change your ini settings to `display_errors=1` and `error_reporting= E_STRICT | E_ALL`).
The `if` is completely pointless either way, here's what I'd write:

```
if ($node->attributes->getNamedItem('name'))
{
    $name = $node->attributes->getNamedItem('name')->nodeValue;
    //assume $arr was declared as $arr = array() -> no field key
    $arr[$name] = isset($arr[$name) ? $arr[$name] : array();//create array if required
}
else
    continue;
if ($node->attributes->getNamedItem('id'))
{
    $id = $node->attributes->getNamedItem('id')->nodeValue;
    $arr[$name][$id] = array();//assuming id is unique, else => ternary like above
}
else
    continue;
if (!$node->attributes->getNamedItem('field_name'))//note the !
    continue;
//field_name exists
$arr[$name][$id][$node->attributes->getNamedItem('field_name')->nodeValue] = $node->nodeValue;
```

The code above could be shortened using a nested loop, though:

```
//inside foreach ($fields as $node)
$names = array(
    'name'       => null,
    'id'         => null,
    'field_name' => null
);
foreach ($names as $name => $val)
{
    if (!$node->attributes->getNamedItem($name))
        continue 2;//continue 2 breaks this loop, has the effect of continue in the outer loop
    $names[$name] = $node->attributes->getNamedItem($name)->nodeValue;
}
//set $arr
```

Putting it all together:

```
$fields = $dom->getElementsByTagName(
    strtolower(
        trim(
            $field
        )
    )
);
$names = array(
    'name'       => null,
    'id'         => null,
    'field_name' => null
);
$arr = array();
foreach ($fields as $node)
{
    if (!$node->hasAttributes())
        continue;//no attributes, skip
    foreach ($names as $key => $val)
    {
        $val = $node->attributes->getNamedItem($key);//saves typing
        if (!$val)
            continue 2;
        $names[$key] = $val->nodeValue;//<-- notably here
    }
    //if we get here, all attributes in $names were found
    //Assuming id is unique:
    if (!isset($arr[$names['name']])
        $arr[$names['name']] = array();
    $arr[$names['name']][$names['id']] = array(
        $names['field_name'] => $node->nodeValue
    );
}
var_dump($arr);//should be exactly what you're after
```

If none of the attribute values (like id, name and field_name) are guaranteed to be unique, you could write:

```
if (!isset($arr[$names['name']]))
    $arr[$names[$name]] = array(
        $names['id'] => array(
            $names['field_name'] => $node->nodeValue
        );
    );
else if (!isset($arr[$names['name']][$names['id']]))
    $arr[$names[$name]][$names['id']] = array(
        $names['field_name'] => $node->nodeValue
    );
else
    $arr[$names[$name]][$names['id']][$names['field_name']] = $node->nodeValue;
```

Which gives you the desired output, still.